# Wordpress Local Installation - cURL error 60: SSL certificate

Tags: wordpress, ssl, curl, wamp, http-proxy

I'm pulling my hair out of this following issue, which I have scoured the internet for and come across a number of solutions... only they don't work for me!

Using Wampserver, I have installed Wordpress on a local VM. This is within my work's network, which sits behind a firewall and uses a proxy to get onto the internet.

Wordpress installed fine. And it connects to the internet too via the proxy. but when I try to download any plugins, or it tries to read RSS feeds, I get the following error:

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable  to get local issuer certificate

I feel like I've tried everything. I've downloaded the latest certificate from here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html and updated the php.ini files... all of them, for all versions. I've followed all the advice on all stack overflow pages relating to this error, but the message persists.

Does anyone have any idea? I'm wondering if it's related to being behind a company firewall.

Thanks in advance